# System.StackOverflowException when calling MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, postgresql, npgsql

First, I have a MainWindow(obviously), and then created a new xaml page called LoginWindow.

I have a class file called Server_setup, to store database access data.

**Server_setup**

```
public class Server_setup
{
    public readonly string Server = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server"];
    public readonly string Port = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"];
    public readonly string User_ID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["User_ID"];
    public readonly string Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
    public readonly string Database = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Database"];
}
```

**Inside App.config**

```
...<appSettings>
    <add key="Server" value="localhost" />
    <add key="Port" value="5432" />
    <add key="User_ID" value="postgres" />
    <add key="Password" value="admin" />
    <add key="Database" value="TestDatabase" />
</appSettings>...
```

Everything is working fine, user can login from LoginWindow and directed to MainWindow.
The problem is when I tried to add a new page called UpdateWindow.

After much problem hunting(entering code line by line), I realized that I got OverflowException when I declaring mainWindow inside the UpdateWindow.

**LoginWindow**

```
public partial class LoginWindow : Window
{
    private readonly Server_setup server_Setup = new Server_setup();
    private readonly NpgsqlConnection iConnect = new NpgsqlConnection();
    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    public LoginWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        iConnect = new NpgsqlConnection
                                   (connectionString: $"Server = {server_Setup.Server};Port = {server_Setup.Port}; User ID = {server_Setup.User_ID};Password = {server_Setup.Password};Database = {server_Setup.Database}");
    }
```

**MainWindow**

```
    private readonly Server_setup server_Setup = new Server_setup();
    private readonly NpgsqlConnection iConnect = new NpgsqlConnection();
    UpdateWindow updateWindow = new UpdateWindow();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        iConnect = new NpgsqlConnection
               (connectionString: $"Server = {server_Setup.Server};Port = {server_Setup.Port}; User ID = {server_Setup.User_ID};Password = {server_Setup.Password};Database = {server_Setup.Database}");
    }
```

**UpdateWindow**

```
 public partial class UpdateWindow : Window
{
    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow(); //Error happened when this code is inserted
    public UpdateWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

[image]

[image]
Any idea why the error occurred?

Looking at the call stack, the code is indeed recurring between MainWindow and LoginWindow

Comment: You could look at the call stack or post it here.

Comment: Hint for general diagnostic purposes: did you try removing everything database-related from your code? It would still show the same problem, but then you wouldn't need to include anything about databases in your question...

Comment: You should usually never create more than one MainWindow instance. You can always access the existing one by `var mainWindow = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you create an instance of `MainWindow`, you create an instance of `UpdateWindow`. Whenever you create an instance of `UpdateWindow`, you create an instance of `MainWindow`... which will then create another instance of `UpdateWindow`, which will create another instance of `MainWindow`, etc.

We can't really tell enough about your UI to know what you're trying to achieve here, but you've got to get rid of that recursion. It seems unlikely that you *really* want to create a new instance of `MainWindow` for each `UpdateWindow`. Perhaps `MainWindow` should "tell" the `UpdateWindow` about itself (either through a constructor parameter or a property)?

Comment: What I want to achieve is some kind "header-like" tab. The tab contain several buttons(for now only update page). MainWindow and UpdateWindow have the same tab.
When I click update button from MainWindow, I got directed from MainWindow to UpdateWindow.
When I click main button from UpdateWindow, I got directed from UpdateWindow to MainWindow.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really follow... if you want a tabbed user interface, use a single window with a tab control. But either way, you shouldn't need the two tabs to *each* create an instance of the other.